# FatalError, Py_Initialize

Tags: python, pygame

I am having this problem where i try and run Python 3.4 with the Pygame library, 
but I get an error that says:

```
Fatal Python error: Py_Initialize: unable to load the file system codec
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Python34\Lib\encodings\__init__.py", line 31, in <module>
ImportError: No module named 'codecs'
```

I am kinda a basic Python writer so I have no idea what this means.

IDE: Sublime Text 3

P.S. I added Python to PATH variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The module named 'codecs' could not be found in the module library of your python installation.

Please make sure you installed the right pygame installer for your python version into the right folder.

Note: Pygame initially was only supported for python2.7, double check if you are using a python3.4 compatible version. Often these type of errors occour when 2.7 modules are expected that were renamed or no longer existant in 3 or you are trying to use code written in 2.7 with 3.